# Psych function describe() with Embedded Vector Returns Error in Var

Tags: r, for-loop, psych, describe

I'd like to use `describe()` passing vectors that are embedded in other vectors so that I can use the function in a `for` loop. 
I have the following data that contains grades for a group of students.
I would like to get descriptive statistics for the 5 different groups the 130 students are sorted into, so I create one subset for each group.

```
pr3 <- read.csv("data.csv", head = T, sep = ";")

G1A <- subset(pr3, group == "1A")
G1B<- subset(pr3, group == "1B")
```

Now calling `describe()` as follows works perfectly:

```
describe(G1A)
```

However, grouping the subsets into a vector `names` and passing an index of `names` to `describe()` won't work:

```
names <- c(G1A, G1B)
describe(names[1])

Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  is.atomic(x) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
>
```

How could I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place your subsets/data frames in a vector and call them in this way.

If you call `str(names[1])` to see the structure of your vector, you will see why it doesn't work.

Instead you might want to place the two data frames in a list in order to call them with your second line. Like this:

```
names <- list(G1A, G1B)
describe(names[1])
```